# Error on install modules with composer in Magneto 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, composer

I have installed Magento 2.3.1 and PHP 7.2.31 and I have run below command,

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` **composer require company/module --no-plugins**

and getting error like below,

```
 Problem 1
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 102.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.1].
```

Any solution on this?

Comment: Upgrade php version to 7.1.3 or 7.2.0 from 7.0.33. Your current PHP version is 7.0.33. And restart the Server as Well.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands as well after upgrade the PHP version

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If above commands do not work. Run below commands as well

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/php
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php7.1 /usr/bin/php
```

Comment: enabled PHP 7.2.31  and restarted server but still getting same error

Comment: Your PHP version still 7.0
Run these two commands:
sudo rm /usr/bin/php
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/bin/php

Also go through this: https://serverfault.com/questions/895746/switch-from-php-7-2-to-7-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-apache

Comment: I followed all steps, it is showing PHP 7.2.31 after run "php -v" command but still getting same error